# Pacific Image PowerSlide X vs Braun MULTIMAG SlideScan 7000 Film Scanner

Tags: 35mm, scanning, slides, scanner

What is the difference between these two scanners? It looks like the specs are the same, but the price is not.

Will the Braun include software, and the Pacific not?

I found that the Braun had a "Infrared channel: integrated". Is that what is different?

And how about the image output. Is that any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with those particular scanners, but I did have a PrimeFilm 3600U.  It only managed a few rolls of film before breaking down, so that completely turned me off of any of the company's other products.

As for the Braun Multimag SlideScan 7000, this [review](https://www.filmscanner.info/en/BraunMultimagSlideScan7000.html) says it is effectively only 5000dpi even though it is advertised as 10000dpi.  The rest of the review appeared reasonable.   Though it may be a perfectly good product, I see misleading advertising as a red flag.

All scanners include some sort of software, though often they are little more than glorified drivers.  This is the case with major brands as well.

Infrared channels are to assist with dust removal.  They can be very helpful for color film.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the review! Is infrared channel processing a separate scan? And would that require any manual processing?

Comment: I haven't used the scanner, so don't know whether IR is captured in a single pass.  Usually use of the IR channel to remove dust is automated by the scanner software.   If it isn't, it's not difficult to use the IR channel as an in-painting/healing mask.